# MySql calendar table and performances

Tags: mysql, performance, join, calendar

for a project i'm working on, i have a single table with two dates meaning a range of dates and i needed a way to "multiply" my rows for every day in between the two dates.

So for instance i have start 2017-07-10, end 2017-07-14
I needed to have 4 lines with 2017-07-10, 2017-07-11, 2017-07-12, 2017-07-13

In order to do this i found here someone mentioning using a "calendar table" with all the dates for years.

So i built it, now i have these two simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `time_sample` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`societa_id`),
  KEY `start_idx` (`start`),
  KEY `end_idx` (`end`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=222 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table contains my date ranges, start and end are indexed, the primary key is an incremental int.
Sample Row:

```
id  start   end
1   2015-05-13  2015-05-18
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `time_dimension` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `td_dbdate_idx` (`db_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This has a date indexed for every day for many years to come.
Sample row:

```
id  db_date
20120101    2012-01-01
```

Now, i made the join:

```
select * from time_sample s join time_dimension t on (t.db_date >= start and t.db_date < end);
```

This takes 3ms. Even if my first table is HUGE, this query will always be very quick (max i've seen was 50ms with a lot of records).

The issue i have is while grouping results (i need them grouped for my application):

```
select * from time_sample s join time_dimension t on (t.db_date >= start and t.db_date < end) group by db_date;
```

This takes more than one second with not so many rows in the first table, increasing dramatically. Why is this happening and how can i avoid this?

Changing the data types doesn't help, having the second table with just one column doesn't help.

Can i have suggestions, please :(

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code. Incidentally, id in time_dimension is completely redundant.

Comment: you're right, but these are just two sample tables, my actual database differs. I've tested performances on these two tho.

Comment: Also, store dates as dates, and place the index on (start,end).

Comment: Im not sure this will help you, but data type for date column(start, end, db_date) should be equal in both tables

Comment: @Zeljka It will help tremendously.

Comment: thanks for answer :)

Comment: Having all varchars helped, taking it from 1second to 450ms.

Comment: Arrrghh*@*!! :-(

Comment: adding as key  KEY `start` (`start`,`end`) didn't help. These read times are far too high, do i have an alternative for the same result?

Comment: I just don't believe that.

Comment: if they're all DATE 600ms, all VARCHAR 430ms, if types don't match (DATE - VARCHAR), 1sec. Still, far too high. I need some solution max 0.15s with a lot of data. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Get rid of `ids`.  Use some other column(s) as the PK.  Use `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this result...

I have a calendar table with lots of dates: calendar(dt) where dt is a PRIMARY KEY DATE data type.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_sample;

CREATE TABLE time_sample (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  start date not NULL,
  end date null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY (start,end)
);

INSERT INTO time_sample (start,end) VALUES  ('2010-03-13','2010-05-09);

SELECT * 
  FROM calendar x 
  JOIN time_sample y 
    ON x.dt BETWEEN y.start AND y.end;
+------------+----+------------+------------+
| dt         | id | start      | end        |
+------------+----+------------+------------+
| 2010-03-13 |  1 | 2010-03-13 | 2010-05-09 |
| 2010-03-14 |  1 | 2010-03-13 | 2010-05-09 |
| 2010-03-15 |  1 | 2010-03-13 | 2010-05-09 |
| 2010-03-16 |  1 | 2010-03-13 | 2010-05-09 |
...
| 2010-05-09 |  1 | 2010-03-13 | 2010-05-09 |
+------------+----+------------+------------+
58 rows in set (0.10 sec)

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM calendar x JOIN time_sample y ON x.dt BETWEEN y.start AND y.end;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | system | start         | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    1 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL |   57 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Even with a GROUP BY, I'm struggling to reproduce the problem. Here's a simple COUNT...

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE dt, COUNT(1) FROM calendar x JOIN time_sample y WHERE x.dt BETWEEN y.start AND y.end GROUP BY dt ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC LIMIT 3;
+------------+----------+
| dt         | COUNT(1) |
+------------+----------+
| 2010-04-03 |        2 |
| 2010-05-05 |        2 |
| 2010-03-13 |        2 |
+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.36 sec)

EXPLAIN
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE dt, COUNT(1) FROM calendar x JOIN time_sample y WHERE x.dt BETWEEN y.start AND y.end GROUP BY dt ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC LIMIT 3;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | y     | index | start         | start   | 7       | NULL |       2 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | x     | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | NULL | 1000001 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: the issue is not reading but grouping. My last query.
select * from time_sample s join time_dimension t on (t.db_date >= start and t.db_date < end) group by db_date;

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, so I don't understand why you're grouping

Comment: well my table as i wrote is far bigger, in this case i'd have to count(*) rows grouped for every db_date, eventually also doing some other calculations, but let's just consider i need to group by date, since i see it as a huge performance problem

Comment: I just get the sense that we're trying to solve a problem that's quite different from the one being asked.

Comment: no, the problem is the same. i just need to find a fast way to achieve the same as  select count(*) from time_sample s join time_dimension t on (t.db_date >= start and t.db_date < end) group by db_date;
Since it's a web application, it can't take 0.5s with so little data, i need it faster.

Comment: Does changing ON to WHERE make any difference?

Comment: how to make it a where? The only way i found being far better is a triple join for now:
select * from time_sample s 
 join time_dimension t on (s.start = t.db_date) 
 join time_dimension t2 on (s.end = t2.db_date) 
 join time_dimension t3 on (t3.id >= t.id and t3.id < t2.id) 
group by t3.db_date;

This takes all from 450ms to 170ms. It's faster, but i'm sure it could be way better somehow.

Comment: ? You replace the word 'on' with the word 'where' !?!?

Comment: Erm, did you try?

Comment: you're not helping, sure i tried! "You have an error in your SQL syntax; "

Comment: Definitely if I replace the word 'on' with the 'where' in the above code, it'll work just fine.

Comment: I'm struggling to help, because I'm struggling to reproduce the performance failure. See edit.

Comment: if you add a thousands records you'll see. You already have 3 rows in set (0.36 sec) which is very high since your dataset is small

Comment: So you have a 1000 start and end ranges?

Comment: Hm, I'm convinced we can improve on this - I'm a little surprised none of the optimization gurus have stuck their noses over the parapet.