# Number of companies who started paying by how long it took them since signing up

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In this, I want to record the number of schemes who started paying by how long it took them since signing up from Jan-17 till Dec-17,
I wrote this query which it counts the number of companies who signed up 1 month ago(as per month) and not yet paid.

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(c.created_at) 'YEAR',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 1 and k.created_at > '2017-02-31', c.id, NULL))'January',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 2 and k.created_at > '2017-03-28', c.id, NULL)) 'February',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 3 and k.created_at > '2017-04-31', c.id, NULL)) 'March',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 4 and k.created_at > '2017-05-30', c.id, NULL)) 'April',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 5 and k.created_at > '2017-06-31', c.id, NULL)) 'May',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 6 and k.created_at > '2017-07-31', c.id, NULL)) 'June',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 7 and k.created_at > '2017-08-31', c.id, NULL)) 'July',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 8 and k.created_at > '2017-09-31', c.id, NULL)) 'August',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 9 and k.created_at > '2017-10-31', c.id, NULL)) 'September',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 10 and k.created_at > '2017-11-31', c.id, NULL)) 'October',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 11 and k.created_at > '2017-12-31', c.id, NULL)) 'November',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(c.created_at) = 12 and k.created_at > '2018-01-31', c.id, NULL)) 'December'
FROM
    companies c join employees e on c.id=e.company_id
    join (select employee_id,min(c.created_at) created_at from contributions c join employees e
    on c.employee_id=e.id group by e.company_id) k 
    on e.id=k.employee_id
WHERE
    c.created_at between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY YEAR(c.created_at)
```

The number of companies who signed up 2 months ago and not yet paid. I need to do that for the hall year (3,4,5,6,7,8,910,11,12 month difference between signing up and first payment) as I am new to MySQL I was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this rather than keep repeating the same query and change the date for each time period? and how can I count the Number of companies who signed up 7-12 months ago and not yet contributed?

Comment: " I was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this rather than keep repeating the same query and change the date for each time period " Your PIVOTing your data in MySQL this is the shortest method possible.. Some databases implemented PIVOT SQL statement for this... "change the date for each time period " you could design a calendar table what hold the date periods and join with that table -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410934/mysql-calendar-table-and-performances